# Use Cmake to run CppuTests

Tags: linux, cmake

I have used CMake to make a library and then made a test exe.  After building, I would like to automatically run my test cases.  Here is my CMakeLists.txt.  It makes the .exe OK but does not run it. I am using Linux.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.7) 
project (tests)

set(LIBRARY_NAME exetests)
set(LIBRARY_SOURCES RunAllTests.cpp Tests.cpp )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC -Werror -O2 -std=c++0x -g")

add_executable(exetests ${LIBRARY_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(exetests CppUTest )
target_link_libraries(exetests CppUTestExt )
target_link_libraries(exetests testLibrary )

#THIS IS WRONG.  EXE is not Run
add_custom_target( COMMAND ./exetests )
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [CTest](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/ctest.1.html) for testing of executables created by CMake. In your CMakeLists.txt, use commands `enable_testing` and [add_test](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_test.html)

```
...
enable_testing()
...
add_executable(exetests ${LIBRARY_SOURCES})
...
add_test(NAME mytest1 COMMAND exetests)
```

in your binary directory, compile `make exetests` and run testing by `ctest`. Some additional information could be found on [CMake Wiki](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest).

Comment: What I am looking for is for the tests to be run automatically when I build the code.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The second signature adds a custom command to a target such as a library or executable. This is useful for performing an operation before or after building the target. The command becomes part of the target and will only execute when the target itself is built. If the target is already built, the command will not execute.

```
add_executable(RunAllTests RunAllTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RunAllTests imp_cpputest LedDriverTest LedDriver sprintfTest RuntimeErrorStub)
add_custom_command( TARGET RunAllTests COMMAND cd ../bin && ./RunAllTests   POST_BUILD)
```

Comment: While this is the way you'd go about it, it's generally a bad idea to have *all* tests run after each and every build. It just doesn't scale.